# type mismatch storing cell value in VBA array

Tags: arrays, excel, types, mismatch

This works with the MsgBox but not when I uncomment the assignment statement I get a type mismatch error.  I have an unknown length of strings starting in D1 that I want to store in the array MyArr.

```
Dim MyArr As Variant   
Range("D1").Select
I = 1

While ActiveCell <> Empty
    MsgBox ("this is in the active cell:" & ActiveCell.Value)
'   MyArr(I) = ActiveCell.Value
    I = I + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Wend
```

Comment: MyArr(I) will fail, as MyArr has not been defined as an array. If you know the ending condition for your set of strings, then a range could be built that can be assigned to an array

Answer (score 1):

`MyArr(I)` will fail, as MyArr has not been defined as an array. Looking at your code, it seems you would like MyArr to contain all the strings found from D1 down to the first empty cell

```vb
Dim MyArr
MyArr=Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown))
If VarType(MyArr)>vbArray then 'more than 1 cell returned
    'D1 is in MyArr(1,1)
    'D2 is in MyArr(2,1)
    '...
    'Lastcell is in MyArr(Ubound(MyArr),1)
Else 'Only one cell found with text
    'D1 is in MyArr 
    'note no () -> one cell = no array
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Sean!  Workiing but locking up when I try to access MyArr when it is in the ELSE condition. tried MyArr, MyArr(1) and MyArr(1,1) but kept locking up.

Comment: @MichaelDehnel: What do you mean by locking up?

Comment: if you get to the else statement, then `MyArr` is the variable to use, not `MyArr(...`. I would check the value you get from the `VarType(MyArr)` to see that it is returning the type of variable you expect. [This page](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/vartype-function-HA001228932.aspx) will tell you what the values are that are returned by **VarType**

Comment: MyArr = Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown))  I see my issue but still working on solution.  UBound is hugh when only a single value in D1 and my for loop gets stuck

Comment: Found a work around `MyArr = Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp))` also than you have a reason to use the else if